# Issue regarding displaying selected location of SCNView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8, scenekit

I was trying to prepare a 3d Human body part selection for Medical app.

In which i need to show a selected Location of geometry.

But the problem i am facing to achieve this process is , when i touch the body from front view , the circle (Which indicates selected location.) is parallel to body.

But when i apply the same thing from back or side view , it doesn't draw parallel.

Here is the screen shot.[image: Front view of 3D view,]
[image: Side view of 3D view]

The code i have applied for

```
-(void)HandleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
CGPoint p = [sender locationInView:self.sceneView];
NSMutableArray *hitResults = nil;
hitResults = [[self.sceneView hitTest:p options:nil] mutableCopy];
if([hitResults count] > 0){
    __block SCNHitTestResult *result = [hitResults objectAtIndex:0];
    float circleArea = .5;
    SCNPlane * plane = [SCNPlane planeWithWidth:circleArea height:circleArea];
    plane.cornerRadius = circleArea/2.0;
    plane.firstMaterial.diffuse.contents = [UIColor redColor];
    SCNNode *shapeNode = [SCNNode nodeWithGeometry: plane];
    shapeNode.position = SCNVector3Make(result.localCoordinates.x, result.localCoordinates.y, result.localCoordinates.z+.1);
    [result.node addChildNode:shapeNode];
    UIAlertController * alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Give a title to selected Human body area." preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    __block UITextField * bodyAreaField;
    [alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField * _Nonnull textField) {
        bodyAreaField = textField;
    }];
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Set" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
        NSMutableArray * array = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"SelectedParts"] mutableCopy];
        if(!array)
        {
            array = [NSMutableArray new];
        }
        NSDictionary * dict = @{@"BodyArea":bodyAreaField.text,
                                @"BodyArea_X_position":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result.localCoordinates.x],
                                @"BodyArea_Y_position":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result.localCoordinates.y],
                                @"BodyArea_Z_position":[NSNumber numberWithFloat:result.localCoordinates.z]};
        [array addObject:dict];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:array forKey:@"SelectedParts"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        NSLog(@"stored body parts %@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"SelectedParts"]);
    }]];
    [alert addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {
    }]];
    [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:^{
    }];
}
}
```

Here is the demo , that i am trying to create 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/i7y28enid51d4cw/Selection%20of%20body%20part.mov?dl=0

Comment: When you say "it doesn't draw paralleI" - is it  your expectation that both markers are on the same plane or do you want them to face the camera?  Can you clarify what the expected behavior is?

Comment: I just want the circle (Touched point highlight) to be parallel to the body part.

For Example , when i touch the solder the circle should be parallel to solder.

If i touch the back it should be parallel to back , no need to be exact when i say parallel , it should be like point on the chest i have shown in above images.

It will be fine , if those circle moves or transforms when i do the same with 3D body.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `SCNBillboardConstraint` to each of the planes containing your circles. That will keep them oriented to the camera. You'll also have to make them children of the scene's root node, instead of children of the body, so that they can move independently of the body.